# How to use call back in FactoryGirl 3.3 to create child object in has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, factory-bot

This question probably has been asked many times. Here is our version. There are user and user_level model in our rails 3.1 app. A user has_many user_levels.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_levels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_levels, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :user_levels
end

class UserLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  validates :position, :presence => true
end
```

Here is what we have in FactoryGirl 3.3:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user_level do 
    position             "admin"
    user
  end

  factory :user do     
    name                  "Test User"
    login                 'testuser'
    password              "password1"

    factory :user_with_levels do
      #user_levels
      after(:create) do |user|
        FactoryGirl(:user_level, :user => user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`u = FactoryGirl.build(:user_with_levels) or u = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_levels)` are used in our rspec. The after create callback did not work and there are errors saying `Validation failed: User levels can't be blank`. What's wrong with the callback above? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that works. It is based on the following post by Tim Riley: http://icelab.com.au/articles/factorygirl-and-has-many-associations/

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user_level do 
    position             "admin"
    user
  end

  factory :user do     
    name                  "Test User"
    login                 'testuser'
    password              "password1"

    #user_levels
    after(:build) do |user|
      user.user_levels << FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :user => user)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem (user level can't be blank) is because there is no user level when user is saved. User level needs to be built along with the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because validations on your nested models fire whenever `create` tries to `save` a `user` factory. Have you tried using an `after(:build)` callback instead?

Comment: A step towards the right direction. Solution posted below. Thanks.